# modx evolution external database

Tags: php, mysql, rss, modx

I have 3 seperate modx evolution website. All 3 websites are completely different and therefore run off a seperate database. However for the news and events pages of each website i would like them to all run from the database of the 1 of the 3 websites. I this possible? is there an extra already created for this purpose?

I have looked into the possibility of using an RSS feed, but would rather have them running directly from the database as this would allow a news article to be added from any of the 3 websites.

Thanks,
Sean.

Comment: how about http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-implementation.html ? you would replicate needed tables from master database and no need to change any code

Comment: yes it is possible, no there is not an extra. but you are in for a good deal of work. I'll look up the appropriate docs and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your extra tables in one modx instance & access them externally ~ however they will need to be on the same file system. I am not aware of a method to do this VIA http/API etc.  See here.

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Loading+MODx+Externally

What you will want to do is create your extra table and extend modx using xPDO, it's a fair bit of work to get setup initially but worth it in the long run. This is the best example for getting started, although you will not be extending anything [but modx] it does give you useful examples of creating your schema and registering it with modx.

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Extending+modUser

and

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Custom+Database+Tables+in+your+3rd+Party+Components

Finally, there IS an extra that will generate all your schema files for you, however I can't seem to find what it is called... sorry. If you have multiple tables using foreign keys it may not be all that useful to you as it won't create the relationships in the files it generates.

Comment: Thank you, but ive decided to use the RSS feed method as it much easier and quicker. But im sure this will be of help to others in the future.