# Modx - Add custom field to mod_site_content

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is it possible to add a custom field to `modx_site_content`? What I'm trying to accomplish, is to add a field `t_id`. I've already added this in the database. However, when I save it using: `$object->save();` nothing is saved for that field, it just comes up as `Null`.

The version I'm using is: MODX Revolution 2.2.4-pl (June 14, 2012)

Comment: in order to add a field like that you would have to hack the modx core code and schema - I'll dig up the docs/tutorials on how to do that correctly.

Comment: You will have to regenerate the table-object that is used by xpdo. check `write-scheme` and `parse-scheme`, but you don't want to do this on the original table. make another one.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like editing the core files is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually - I've answered that question before. You want to create a separate table and schema.

[modx evolution external database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197979/modx-evolution-external-database)

however - it looks like you want to add a field so that you can call it as part of the page/template in modx? You may have to write a plugin to extract that data at the same time as the resource.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but now the [ClassExtender extra](https://bobsguides.com/classextender-class.html) will create the additional table for you based on your schema, add the additional fields to the Create/Edit Resource panel with a plugin, and save those field values to the table in the DB when the Resource is saved in the Manager. This can save a lot of time and trouble.

If you can wait, a new version that works in MODX 3 should be released soon.